# Doing conditional masking with batches in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just occurred a problem when I'm using `Tensorflow`.
Suppose I have a tensor with `[batch_size, 3]`
For example, let say I have a tensor with batch_size of 3:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 2, 1]]
```

My problem is that, I want to "mask out" the elements after the element 2, which my final output should be:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0]]
```

I'm wondering if there is anyway to accomplish this in tensorflow? Since I always get the error "object does not support item assignment".
Thank you so much!

Comment: You need a separate placeholder that keeps track of the lengths and then you can use the sequence_mask op.

Comment: I did manage to find the sequence_mask op, but the tensor is generated through some other ops during computation, so I wonder how can I find the first position of "2"? Since there are cases that no "2" (or multiple "2"s) are generated, so the segment_min trick doesn't work for me :(

Comment: You can probably find the first position